# Import preact hooks module locally (offline)

Tags: javascript, import, hook, offline, preact

I am trying to use preact hooks in my web application. I am going through no build tools route.
Following is the code I am using to do the job

```
import { h, render, Component } from './preact.mjs';
import { useState } from './hooks.mjs';
import { htm } from './htm.mjs';

const html = htm.bind(h);

function MyComponent() {
    return html`<button>Click Me!</button>`
}

render(html`<${MyComponent}/>`, document.getElementById("root"));
```

But I am getting following error in browser console

Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “preact” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.

I believe below line in hooks.mjs is the cause for problem. It is not referencing `preact.mjs` but just `preact`

```
import{options as n} from "preact";
```

How to solve this. I do not want to manually modify this line but use it as is. There should be a reason why the default library is shipped as it. Am I missing something here.

PS: I cannot use CDN. I need to use this in a system without internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting the code for `preact.mjs` and `hooks.mjs` from? If you're copy/pasting from NPM, the published content is meant for consumption in Node/environments that support Node's module resolution. This is not usable directly in the browser.

However, what you can use are import maps, which support this behavior. Simply insert this in the head of the document, before you import your script:

```html
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "preact": "./preact.mjs",
            "preact/hooks": "./hooks.mjs"
        }
    }
</script>
```

This will map `preact` to `./preact.mjs`, correcting the specifiers to avoid errors.

Comment: I am not using npm files. I downloaded the releases available in preactjs repository. Using `importmap` worked. Thank you.

Comment: Releases from the GitHub repo are exactly what's published to NPM, i.e., not meant for this use case really.

Comment: Can you give your advise on creating preact app using no build tools route. (with out using CDN or NPM).

Comment: Anything with dependencies, the best bet would be to compile the source yourself. However, the easiest way for Preact + hooks + htm would be to use `htm`'s standalone build. It includes Preact, hooks, and htm all in a single file. https://unpkg.com/htm@3.1.1/preact/standalone.mjs